# Extract data from pdf files with R

Tags: r, extract, pdf-extraction

I am trying to extract data (tables) from pdf files and store them as data frames.

```r
library(pdftools)
library(tabulizerjars)
library(tabulizer)
library(tidyverse)


f <- file.path("D:/Araratbank/Statement USD-pages-1.pdf")

#using pdf tools package

text <- pdf_text(f)

text
#> [1] "                                                                                                                                                              ´ ³ÝÏ³ÛÇÝ ·³Õï ÝÇù +\r\n                                                                                                                                                                         Î³ï³ñáÕ`\r\n                                                                                                                                îå»ó` Ø³ñ·³ñÛ³Ý ²ÝÝ³ èáµ»ñïÇF226 17/12/19 13:45:39\r\n                                                           ø²Ôì²Ìø ´²ÜÎ²ÚÆÜ Ð²ÞìÆò\r\n                                                         ïñ³Ù³¹ñÙ³Ý ³Ùë³ÃÇíÁ         17/12/19 13:46:16\r\n    ´ ³ÝÏ                                                     AM24149, ÚáõÝÇµ³ÝÏ äñÇí» Ù³ëÝ³×ÛáõÕ\r\n    Ð³×³Ë áñ¹Ç ³Ýáõ ÝÁ/³Ýí ³Ýáõ ÙÁ                            §²¸²ØÆàôØ¦ êäÀ\r\n    Ð³ë ó»                                                    Ð²Ú²êî²Ü ºñ¨³Ý èáõµÇÝÛ³Ýó ÷áÕ. 21/3-19\r\n    Ð³×³Õáñ¹Ç Ñ ³ßí Ç Ñ ³Ù³ñÁ/² ñÅáõ ÛÃÁ                      24149000206001                 USD\r\n    ø³Õí ³ÍùÇ Ñ ³Ù³ñ\r\n    Ü ³Ë áñ¹ ù³Õí ³ÍùÇ Ó¨³í áñÙ³Ý ³Ùë ³ÃÇí                    01/09/19\r\n    êÏ½µÝ³Ï³Ý ÙÝ³óáñ¹                                         01/09/19    CR   USD         358,048.19\r\n    F226                                                                                                                                                                  --1\r\n²Ùë ³ÃÇí     ö ³ë ï ³ÃÕÃÇ    ö ³ë ï ³ÃÕÃÇ  ¶ áõ Ù³ñ      DB/ êï ³óáÕÇ/ ì×³ñáÕÇ       êï ³óáÕÇ/ ì×³ñáÕÇ          êï ³óáÕÇ/ í ×³ñáÕÇ                      Ü å³ï ³ÏÁ\r\n                Ñ ³Ù³ñ     Ñ ÕÙ³Ý Ñ ³Ù³ñÁ                 CR   Ñ ³ßí Ç Ñ ³Ù³ñ         ³Ýáõ ÝÁ/³Ýí ³Ýáõ ÙÁ               µ³ÝÏ\r\n                                                                                 PEPSICO HOLDINGS LLC          BLICRUMM / HSBC BANK     INVOICE 03/00362660-19 DD 07.08.19A CC. TO\r\n 02/09/19  190902021464049 190902049382049       7,336.83 DB   38410000000213      141580,RU SSIA,MOSCOW              (RR) OOO           CONTRACT N PS/AD 001/02-18D D 14.02.18\r\n                                                                                   SANDORA LTD         57262,    CITIUAUK / CITIBANK   INV 32015 DD 06.08.19 ACC. TO CONT RACT N\r\n 02/09/19  190902021461049 190902049391049      12,260.20 DB   38410000000213     UKRAINA, N IKOLAEVSKAYA             (UKRAINE)            S-19-3972 DD 01.06.2019 FOR NATURAL\r\n                                                                                        JSC PERMALKO,         AVTBRUMMXXX / URALSIB          INVOICE 255 DD 03.09.19 ACC. TO C\r\n 03/09/19  190903041599049 190903047747049      20,082.24 DB   38410000000213       RUSSIA,614990,G.PERM,             BANK OAO            ONTRACT N282-15 DTD. 16.09.2015 FO R\r\n                                                                                       OOO RODNIK I K         AVTBRUMMXXX / URALSIB       INVOICES 184-190 DD 20.08.19 ACC . TO\r\n 03/09/19  190903041597049 190903047761049      93,139.20 DB   38410000000213       RUSSIA,MOSKOVSKA YA               BANK OAO              CONTRACT N62-M DD 10.05.2016F OR\r\n                                                                                   GLOBAL SPIRITS GROUP MUNIUA22 / TASCOMBANK               INVOICES 18,19 DD 23.08.19 ACC. TOC\r\n 03/09/19  190903041591049 190903047819049      41,015.88 DB   38410000000213     LLC         12 VYACHESLAV     JSC (FORMERLY BANK         ONTRACT N 06/2019-A DD 13.07.19 FOR\r\n                                                                                    ABRAHAM JACOBI- THE        RZBAATWW RAIFFEISEN\r\n 04/09/19  ASW07394/040919 190904088136000      14,307.58 CR   38410000000197        BEER STORE 3-22 S.Y.     BANK INTERNATIONAL AG\r\n                                                                                   M.D. AVIATION SERVICES      RZBAATWW RAIFFEISEN             INV:03092019      DATE 03/09/19\r\n 04/09/19  ASW97492/030919 190904088137000      14,371.58 CR   38410000000197        LTD 30 SHD. GOSHEN       BANK INTERNATIONAL AG\r\n                                                                                   GLOBAL SPIRITS GROUP MUNIUA22 / TASCOMBANK INVOICE 12 DD 09.08.19 ACC. TO CONT RACT\r\n 05/09/19  190905032684049 190905035088049         300.00 DB   38410000000213     LLC         12 VYACHESLAV     JSC (FORMERLY BANK       N 06/2019-A DD 13.07.19 FOR AD VERTISING\r\n                                                                                      LLC WORLD TRADE            BAGAGE22 / BANK OF    INVOICE 809 DD 27.08.19 ACC TO CON TRACT\r\n 05/09/19  190905032676049 190905035147049       6,160.00 DB   38410000000213        COMPANY        GEORGI            GEORGIA           N 071218 DD 07/12/18 FOR TRAN SPORTATION\r\n´³ÝÏ³ÛÇÝ ·³ÕïÝÇù*\r\n                                                                                1\r\n"


#using tabulizer package

statement <- extract_tables(
  file   = f, 
  method = "decide")

str(statement)
#> List of 1
#>  $ : chr [1:20, 1:9] "2Ã\231Ã«3ÃƒÃ‡Ã­" "" "" "02/09/19" ...

statement
#> [[1]]
#>       [,1]           [,2]                [,3]                  
#>  [1,] "2Ã\231Ã«3ÃƒÃ‡Ã­" "Ã¶ 3Ã«Ã¯3ÃƒÃ•ÃƒÃ‡" "Ã¶ 3Ã«Ã¯3ÃƒÃ•ÃƒÃ‡"   
#>  [2,] ""             "Ã‘3Ã\2313Ã±"          "Ã‘Ã•Ã\2313Ã\235 Ã‘3Ã\2313Ã±Ã\201"
#>  [3,] ""             ""                  ""                    
#>  [4,] "02/09/19"     "190902021464049"   "190902049382049"     
#>  [5,] ""             ""                  ""                    
#>  [6,] "02/09/19"     "190902021461049"   "190902049391049"     
#>  [7,] ""             ""                  ""                    
#>  [8,] "03/09/19"     "190903041599049"   "190903047747049"     
#>  [9,] ""             ""                  ""                    
#> [10,] "03/09/19"     "190903041597049"   "190903047761049"     
#> [11,] ""             ""                  ""                    
#> [12,] "03/09/19"     "190903041591049"   "190903047819049"     
#> [13,] ""             ""                  ""                    
#> [14,] "04/09/19"     "ASW07394/040919"   "190904088136000"     
#> [15,] ""             ""                  ""                    
#> [16,] "04/09/19"     "ASW97492/030919"   "190904088137000"     
#> [17,] ""             ""                  ""                    
#> [18,] "05/09/19"     "190905032684049"   "190905035088049"     
#> [19,] ""             ""                  ""                    
#> [20,] "05/09/19"     "190905032676049"   "190905035147049"     
#>       [,4]               [,5] [,6]                         
#>  [1,] "Â¶ Ã¡ÃµÃ\2313Ã± DB/" ""   "ÃªÃ¯3Ã³Ã¡Ã•Ã‡/Ã¬Ã—3Ã±Ã¡Ã•Ã‡"
#>  [2,] ""                 "CR" "Ã‘3ÃŸÃ­Ã‡ Ã‘3Ã\2313Ã±"         
#>  [3,] ""                 ""   ""                           
#>  [4,] "7,336.83"         "DB" "38410000000213"             
#>  [5,] ""                 ""   ""                           
#>  [6,] "12,260.20"        "DB" "38410000000213"             
#>  [7,] ""                 ""   ""                           
#>  [8,] "20,082.24"        "DB" "38410000000213"             
#>  [9,] ""                 ""   ""                           
#> [10,] "93,139.20"        "DB" "38410000000213"             
#> [11,] ""                 ""   ""                           
#> [12,] "41,015.88"        "DB" "38410000000213"             
#> [13,] ""                 ""   ""                           
#> [14,] "14,307.58"        "CR" "38410000000197"             
#> [15,] ""                 ""   ""                           
#> [16,] "14,371.58"        "CR" "38410000000197"             
#> [17,] ""                 ""   ""                           
#> [18,] "300.00"           "DB" "38410000000213"             
#> [19,] ""                 ""   ""                           
#> [20,] "6,160.00"         "DB" "38410000000213"             
#>       [,7]                           [,8]                         
#>  [1,] "ÃªÃ¯3Ã³Ã¡Ã•Ã‡/Ã¬Ã—3Ã±Ã¡Ã•Ã‡"  "ÃªÃ¯3Ã³Ã¡Ã•Ã‡/Ã­Ã—3Ã±Ã¡Ã•Ã‡"
#>  [2,] "3Ã\235Ã¡ÃµÃ\235Ã\201/3Ã\235Ã­3Ã\235Ã¡ÃµÃ\231Ã\201" "Î¼3Ã\235Ã\217"                    
#>  [3,] "PEPSICO HOLDINGS LLC"         "BLICRUMM / HSBC BANK"       
#>  [4,] "141580,RU SSIA,MOSCOW"        "(RR) OOO"                   
#>  [5,] "SANDORA LTD57262,"            "CITIUAUK / CITIBANK"        
#>  [6,] "UKRAINA, N IKOLAEVSKAYA"      "(UKRAINE)"                  
#>  [7,] "JSC PERMALKO,"                "AVTBRUMMXXX / URALSIB"      
#>  [8,] "RUSSIA,614990,G.PERM,"        "BANK OAO"                   
#>  [9,] "OOO RODNIK I K"               "AVTBRUMMXXX / URALSIB"      
#> [10,] "RUSSIA,MOSKOVSKA YA"          "BANK OAO"                   
#> [11,] "GLOBAL SPIRITS GROUP"         "MUNIUA22 / TASCOMBANK"      
#> [12,] "LLC12 VYACHESLAV"             "JSC (FORMERLY BANK"         
#> [13,] "ABRAHAM JACOBI- THE"          "RZBAATWW RAIFFEISEN"        
#> [14,] "BEER STORE 3-22 S.Y."         "BANK INTERNATIONAL AG"      
#> [15,] "M.D. AVIATION SERVICES"       "RZBAATWW RAIFFEISEN"        
#> [16,] "LTD 30 SHD. GOSHEN"           "BANK INTERNATIONAL AG"      
#> [17,] "GLOBAL SPIRITS GROUP"         "MUNIUA22 / TASCOMBANK"      
#> [18,] "LLC12 VYACHESLAV"             "JSC (FORMERLY BANK"         
#> [19,] "LLC WORLD TRADE"              "BAGAGE22 / BANK OF"         
#> [20,] "COMPANYGEORGI"                "GEORGIA"                    
#>       [,9]                                        
#>  [1,] "ÃœÃ¥3Ã¯3Ã\217Ã\201"                              
#>  [2,] ""                                          
#>  [3,] "INVOICE 03/00362660-19 DD 07.08.19A CC. TO"
#>  [4,] "CONTRACT N  PS/AD 001/02-18D D 14.02.18"   
#>  [5,] "INV 32015  DD 06.08.19 ACC. TO CONT RACT N"
#>  [6,] "S-19-3972  DD 01.06.2019 FOR  NATURAL"     
#>  [7,] "INVOICE 255  DD 03.09.19  ACC. TO C"       
#>  [8,] "ONTRACT N282-15  DTD. 16.09.2015 FO R"     
#>  [9,] "INVOICES  184-190  DD 20.08.19  ACC . TO"  
#> [10,] "CONTRACT N62-M  DD 10.05.2016F OR"         
#> [11,] "INVOICES 18,19 DD 23.08.19 ACC. TOC"       
#> [12,] "ONTRACT N 06/2019-A DD 13.07.19 FOR"       
#> [13,] ""                                          
#> [14,] ""                                          
#> [15,] "INV:03092019DATE 03/09/19"                 
#> [16,] ""                                          
#> [17,] "INVOICE 12 DD 09.08.19 ACC. TO CONT RACT"  
#> [18,] "N 06/2019-A DD 13.07.19 FOR AD VERTISING"  
#> [19,] "INVOICE 809  DD 27.08.19 ACC TO CON TRACT" 
#> [20,] "N 071218 DD 07/12/18 FOR TRAN SPORTATION"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Both options return long rows of unstructured and messy data. Is there any other way to extract these type of data from the pdf files (to get the tables as data frames) or I have to clean and tidy these data? You can find the file here : [statement USD](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OxLdDREP9QCQogMnuCkpQg9OC_zy06tM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two options are to tidy up the text yourself, which is possible but difficult, or to try the [pdftools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdftables/index.html) package. This requires you to [sign up for the API](https://pdftables.com/join). You will get quicker results with pdftables, but you will be limited in how many PDFs you can convert. If you have a large number of documents to process, it may be easier to get the position of all the elements on the page with `pdftools::pdf_data`.